# Synonym request for quests: quest

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Could someone suggest [quest](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quest) as a synonym for [quests](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quests)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done. You can [vote here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/quests/synonyms), though a Mod will likely finish the job before democracy can run it's course.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to rely on democracy and mods ... I've no answers on the quests tag and there are no questions for which I can provide one, so I can't vote for it either.

Comment: in b4 democracy

Comment: @badp democracy is overrated anyway ;-)